# WordPress > Contact Form 7 > Dynamic “To” address

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, email

In a Contact Form 7 form, for mail 2 "To" address, I have provided a custom field for the page.

As per instructions on https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/ I have put `[email* targetemail default:post_meta]` on form, and then `[targetemail]` as “To” address for email.

Form validates fine.

When I try to submit the said form, I get the dreaded red border:

> There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.

Primary mail has a static address. This message is being sent fine. So the issue is not with the mail()/SMTP setup.

So, my question is, how can I set a dynamic/variable "To" address in Contact Form 7, so that I am able to emails to different addresses, based on which page the form is inserted into.

Comment: Please also provide link for contact form.

Comment: Means in email To:  you want to manage dynamic email address?

Comment: @PPL Exactly! Here's the link https://executivemba.co/insead-global-executive-mba-europe/ >> Means in email To: you want to manage dynamic email address?